# Two variable limit - moving to polar form and L'hospital rule

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I have to prove that

$$f(x,y) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
\frac{(x-1)^3 + 2(y-2)^3}{(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2}  &  (x,y) \neq (1,2)\\ 
0 & (x,y) = (1,2)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

Is differentiable at $(x,y) = (0,0)$

It is continuous at that point as it is defined well at $(0,0)$ and the partial derivatives also exist and finite:

$f_x(0,0) = \frac{-19}{25} , f_y(0,0) = \frac{52}{25}$

Now in order to prove it is differentiable I need to use this massive limit:

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{ f(x,y) - (f(0,0) + \Delta x f_x(0,0) + \Delta y f_y(0,0))}{\sqrt{(\Delta x )^2 + (\Delta y)^2}} = 0 $$  (I need to prove it is equal to $0$ - otherwise it isn't differentiable)

Where $\Delta x = x - x_0 = x - 0 = x$ and likewise for $\Delta y, ~~ f(0,0) = \frac{17}{5}$

I tried to solve that limit, and moved to polar coordinates by doing:

$ x = r \cos(\theta) , y = r \sin(\theta)$ and so $r \rightarrow 0^+$ :

$$\lim_{r \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{ \frac{(r \cos(\theta) - 1)^3 + 2( r\sin(\theta) - 2)^3}{(r \cos(\theta) - 1)^2 + ( r\sin(\theta) - 2)^2} + \frac{19}{25} r \cos(\theta) - \frac{52}{25} r \sin(\theta) + \frac{17}{5}}{r}$$

Can I use L'hospital rule because now it is a one variable limit? How can I continue from here? because, I can see the $\frac{17}{5}$ will destroy everything and make the limit non-existing.. but I do know it is differentiable at that point + WolframAlpha says the limit is equal to $0$ (Which proves it is differentiable)

Thank you for your kind help!

Comment: You can certainly use L'Hopital. Both the numerator and denominator tend to $0$ when $r\to0$. In the numerator, the constant term is eliminated by $f(r,\theta)$ because the function is defined at $r=0$ and $f(0,\theta)=17/5$. I'm pretty sure there is a sign error in the numerator (the constant term should be negative).

Comment: I don't understand how I should solve this limit, people say it is 0 but I can't figure out how...

Comment: I'll add an answer later today.